# How to get Billing Address from Eloquent model with where clause?

Tags: php, laravel

For example I can use:

```php
$address = $user->address
```

which will return the addresses for the user.

// User.php (model)

```php
public function address()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Address::class, 'refer_id', 'id');
}
```

```php
public function billingAddress()
{
    return $this->address()
        ->where('type', '=', 1)
        ->where('refer_id', '=', $this->id)
        ->first();
}
```

However, I would like to return the BillingAddress for the user depending on this where clause. How do I do it?

**EDIT:**
If I use this inside... OrderController@index it returns correctly

```php
        $orders = Order::with('order_fulfillment', 'cart.product', 'user.address', 'payment')->get();
        return new OrderResource($orders);
```

However, If I change it to:

```php
        $orders = Order::with('order_fulfillment', 'cart.product', 'user.billingAddress', 'payment')->get();
        return new OrderResource($orders);
```

I get this error:
*Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null*

Comment: What is the output of $user-> billingAddress();

Comment: @invalidbot see update

Answer (score 1):

One option is you can use `whereHas` in your query. For example,

```
$orders = Order::with('order_fulfillment', 'cart.product', 'user.address', 'payment')
->whereHas(
 'address', function ($query) {
   $query->where('type', '=', 1)
    ->first();
 }
)->get();
    return new OrderResource($orders);
```

This is one option. try to `dd($orders)` an find if its working.

You had an another option like this, in your model

```
public function address()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Address::class, 'refer_id', 'id');
}
```

Add relations like

```
public function billingAddress()
{
   return $this->hasOne(Address::class, 'refer_id', 'id')->where('type', 1);
}
```

And

```
 public function shippingAddress()
{
   return $this->hasOne(Address::class, 'refer_id', 'id')->where('type', 2);
}
```

Then in your query,

```
$orders = Order::with('order_fulfillment', 'cart.product', 'user.address','user.billingAddress', 'user.shippingAddress', 'payment')->get(); return new OrderResource($orders);
```

Comment: How do I query 2? BillingAddress 1, ShippingAddress 2

Comment: query 2 means ?

Comment: if type = 1.. BillingAddress. If type = 2 shipping address.